# How can I serve manifest file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox, heroku

I want to register app at Firefox marketplace.

There is such requirement:

```
App manifests must be served with a Content-Type header of application/x-web-app-manifest+json.
```

But I can't really get what I'm supposed to do.

Where I should place this line?

**What have I tried:**

Created `.htaccess` with:

```
AddType application/x-web-app-manifest+json .webapp
```

File can be accessed with `mysite.com/manifest.webapp` and it is opened with no errors

Answer (score 1):

In your browser, look at the returned HTTP headers see what the `Content-Type:` is. Unless you are using (for your Heroku app) a buildpack that has Apache in it, simply adding `.htaccess` won't help.

You will need to configure your web framework (rails in this case?) to return a specific `Content-Type` header when your `.webapp` file is requested. An example in Rails would be to create a controller-action just for this file with something like

```
send_file params[:filename], :type => 'application/x-web-app-manifest+json'
```

though I am no Rails expert and there may be better ways of doing it (look into whatever serves static files in Rails).